# using CLISP to make equations given a sequence of numbers

Tags: common-lisp

so i have to use clisp to create 2 equaline equations given a sequence of numbers

IE user enters 2 2 2 2:

2 + 2 = 2 + 2 ; would be valid

2 - 2 = 2 - 2 ; would also be valid

2 = 2 + 2 - 2 ; valid

2 + 2 + 2 = 2 ; not valid

user enters 6 2 2 2:

6 = 2 + 2 + 2 ; valid

6 = 2 * 2 + 2 ; valid

6 + 2 = 2 * 2 ; not valid

The operates of *, /, +, and - are to be used for basic math, and = to signify that Left Hand Side = Right Hand Side.

My problem lies in my lack of any real lisp training and where to start. I think I would have to use macros, but I'm not sure how to use macros or how macros would be used for this.

I know that initially I would have to define a function such as

(defun findequation (a b c d))

But from there I'm lost

Comment: Could you write this in any language other than Lisp? I would start there, and then you could ask "how do I do this in language X, but instead in Lisp".

Comment: I do not see what this has to do with macros.

Comment: "Equaline" is not a word.  What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

First step: create all combinations of the relevant symbols, with the restriction that exactly one `=` should be present.

Example input: `(2 2 2 2)`, `(+ - * / =)`

Example output: `(2 + 2 + 2 = 2)`, `(2 + 2 - 2 = 2)`, `(2 - 2 - 2 = 2)`, …

Second step: use the [shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) to transform the infix list of alternating numbers and symbols into a tree.

Example input: `(2 + 2 = 2 - 2)`

Example output: `(= (+ 2 2) (- 2 2))`

Then you can evaluate that to see if it is true.